# Does it make sense to decorate a @staticmethod with an @lru_cache?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have in python3:

```
class MyClass:
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    @staticmethod
    def run_expensive_computation() -> bool:
        return expensive_function("hard_coded_string")
```

Assuming:

- expensive_function() itself is NOT cached
- "hard_coded_string" will never change so no need to make that as
  input to `run_expensive_computation`

Is it a waste of time to put `@lru_cache(maxsize=None)` here if `run_expensive_computation` takes no inputs ? What will be the key saved in the cache in this case ?

Comment: it makes sense *if you want caching*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga if there is no input, what serves as key to the cache ? Any gotchas in that example ?

Comment: A cache key of `None` is fine. It's easy to test with a simple function that has a `time.sleep()` delay to simulate an expensive function.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure, this is fine and the `lru_cache` handles this case fine.

A wrapper is used that catches the arguments as `*args, **kwargs` and a key is extracted from that. In this case, it is just an empty tuple, if you want to see the details, just look at [the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aca77b5530c34fb2ada0fe02fb83f4c9fa9256f3/Lib/functools.py#L448). That is the Python version, although, CPython will actually use a C implementation found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1237fb6a4b177ce8f750949b9006c58f9f22942e/Modules/_functoolsmodule.c#L818)

As an aside, in the most recent python versions, >= 3.9, you can use [`functools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache) for the case where you use `maxsize=None`, which should be smaller and faster than the LRU cache.

Note: the `functools` caching decorators can not be used in this order with `staticmethod` objects on versions of Python prior to `3.10`. The order of the decorators could be reversed though, and that should work regardless of version.

Comment: `TypeError: the first argument must be callable`.

Comment: @wim not on Python versions >= 3.10

Comment: Right, but on 3.10+ there are other problems. You can not use the staticmethod from an instance. I don't think it's right to say _`lru_cache` handles this case fine_, because it doesn't.

Comment: @wim ah, that is a good point

Answer (score 2):

> Does it make sense to decorate a `@staticmethod` with an `@lru_cache`?

No, it does not. It's bugged/broken - on Python < 3.10 you can not define a class like this at all, and on Python >= 3.10 it will break the staticmethod to do so -  it will no longer be callable from an instance.

It does make sense to decorate a cached method with staticmethod, though:

```
class MyClass:
    @staticmethod
    @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
    def run_expensive_computation() -> bool:
        return expensive_function("hard_coded_string")
```

Answer (score 0):

`lru_cache` adds overhead to the call that isn't needed for such a simple case. Instead, you could have a lock that protects your own cache variable. If it's `None`, you do the expensive work in the lock. Otherwise, return the cache. After the first call, the cost is simply a test for `None`.

```
import threading

class MyClass:

    cache_lock = threading.Lock()
    cache = None

    @staticmethod
    def run_expensive_computation() -> bool:
        if MyClass.cache is None:
            with MyClass.cache_lock:
                if MyClass.cache is None:
                    MyClass.cache = expensive_function("hard_coded_string")
        retrun MyClass.cache
```

Comment: Did you profile it? This is about 20% slower than just using the functools decorator. I guess because this checks for cache hit in Python code, where functools has a C implementation.